# How do I know if there are any more solutions?

Tags: linear-programming

I have done the Einstein's Riddle exercise with linear programming. I implemented [this solutions](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311970636_Application_of_Einstein%27s_riddle_in_solving_construction_machine_allocation_problems)  in Gusek. **How can i tell if there is more than one solution?**

Einsten's riddle:

There are 5 houses in five different colors.
In each house lives a person with a different nationality.
These five owners drink a certain type of beverage, smoke a certain brand of cigar and keep a certain pet.
No owners have the same pet, smoke the same brand of cigar or drink the same beverage.

Constaints:

the Brit lives in the red house

the Swede keeps dogs as pets

the Dane drinks tea

the green house is on the left of the white house

the green house's owner drinks coffee

the person who smokes Pall Mall rears birds

the owner of the yellow house smokes Dunhill

the man living in the center house drinks milk

the Norwegian lives in the first house

the man who smokes blends lives next to the one who keeps cats

the man who keeps horses lives next to the man who smokes Dunhill

the owner who smokes BlueMaster drinks beer

the German smokes Prince

the Norwegian lives next to the blue house

the man who smokes blend has a neighbor who drinks water

**Can I tell which constraints are redundant?**

Thank you for your help

Comment: This https://github.com/0vercl0k/z3-playground/blob/master/einstein_riddle_z3.py finds 5 solutions. Run it, store solutions somewhere. Then try it running without constraints one by one. If without a constraint X solutions are the same - X is redundant.

Comment: (1) you can add a cut (constraint) to the model that forbids the current solution, and re-solve. Repeat until things become infeasible. (2) some redundant constraints may actually help a MIP model (valid constraints). I would not worry about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your decisions/solution will be in the form of binary or integer varibles.

If they are binary, add in a new constraint like the one below:
(Y are all the binaries which were 1 and `Y are binaries which were 0.)

sum(Y) + sum(i-`Y) != |Y|+|`Y|

Keep repeating this till you get an infeasible model. This can be extended to the integer case too.

As for redundancy, you have to manually try removing them and see if the solution changes. However, in terms of reduncancy, you might have cases where constraint A and B are redundant OR constraint C is redundant. You could have multiple sets of potential redundant constraints depending on which you eliminate.